# Largest Contentful Paint increased dramatically when using LazyLoad

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

One of my websites has a really bad LCP, 4.6. I realized that without active lazyload my images, the LCP is 2.0 . The TCB increased by using lazyload, too. So Im thinking it must be my bad JS-Skills, so could give me anyone of you a hint?

My actual code:

```
let lazyImages = [...document.querySelectorAll('img[data-src],iframe[data-src],div[data-bg],header[data-bg]')];
let inAdvance = 300;

function lazyLoad() {
   lazyImages.forEach(image => {
       if ( !image.classList.contains( 'lazyloaded' ) && !image.classList.contains( 'none' ) && image.getBoundingClientRect().top <= window.innerHeight + inAdvance && image.getBoundingClientRect().bottom >= 0) {
           if( image.hasAttribute( 'data-src' ) ){
               image.src = image.dataset.src;
           }

           if( image.hasAttribute( 'data-bg' ) ){
               image.setAttribute( 'style', 'background-image:url( ' + image.dataset.bg + ' );' );
           }

           image.classList.add('lazyloaded');
           //image.onload = () => image.classList.add('lazyloaded');
       }
   })
}

window.addEventListener( 'scroll', lazyLoad, {passive: true} );
window.addEventListener( 'resize', lazyLoad, {passive: true} );
window.addEventListener( 'slick', lazyLoad, {passive: true} );
```

I've already tried a replacement with observer, but there wasnt any improvement by tcb or lcp.

Comment: HI Viewer welcome to SO! Could you please also shareb which lazyloading library you are using and the relevant HTML code ? Thank you

Comment: what is TCB? Used lighthouse for a while but dont recognise any term that fits that? I will pop an answer once you explain that term just to check it isn't relevant, but in essence your LCP time is when the largest paint appears on the screen. If you are lazy loading after loading all of your JS then the loading starts late in the process so your LCP time is late. If you remove lazy loading the image causing the LCP is loaded earlier so your time improves. FYI you should **not** lazy load anything that appears "above the fold" and instead optimise the images etc.

Comment: @LaurentC The code above is my lazyload - code. Its a snippet from the google-devs I've modified to fit my needs. It lazyloads images and iframes. Additionally you can set lazyloading for backgroundimages for divs and header-elemts, too. Im, calling it at the End of my JS with  `lazyLoad();`

My HTML-Markup look like this:

`<img data-src="path to file" src="path to placeholder"/>`

Comment: @GrahamRitchie THX for your explanation and sorry, I've mean TBT (Total Blocking Time), not TBC - my fault. 

Hm, the LCP increase, when I'm loading my above-the-fold-content at the and of my loading-cycle... yeah, thats sounds logical. I will remove the lazyLoading from all that elements and give it a try, but Im thinking that should do the job.

Thank you, I will report the results :)

Comment: @Viewer let me know how you get on, I have also added some general tips into an answer for you on why your TBT is affected, without seeing the page though they may not be the cause. Give them a go and let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Why does my Largest Contentful Paint (LCP) time improve after removing lazy load?

This tends to be an implementation issue.

LCP measures when the largest paint appears on the page. If you use lazy loading and the images are visible "above the fold" (without scrolling) and they are the largest paint on the page then they will be reported as LCP. This can also be the case if just the top of an image is showing.

Now if you are lazy loading them and your JavaScript is loaded late in the page load order it means that the images will get downloaded later, increasing your LCP time.

#### Steps to fix

1. Don't lazy load images that appear "above the fold" just use a standard `<img>` or `<picture>` element.
2. That's it! Lazy load everything that is out of view when the page loads as the performance gains are worth it (as well as improving bandwidth usage etc.).

### Why is my Total Blocking Time (TBT) affected?

TBT is looking for a "quiet time" on the CPU to determine when the main work on the page is done.

What the test also does is scroll the page to the bottom.

Because of this your function is probably being called multiple times in quick succession and bottle-necking the CPU (bearing in mind that the CPU has a 4x slowdown applied for mobile scoring to simulate a real world mobile device with less powerful CPU.)

#### Probable causes / possible solutions

Because you have the event listener set to fire on `'scroll'` it is being fired multiple times and I assume you have multiple images on the page.

One thing you could do is to change your actual function so it isn't having to do as many loops each time.

i.e. once you have set your image `src` or background `style`, remove that item from your `lazyImages` list. This reduces the amount of items that need checking when the page is scrolled and will result in better performance.

Also just check how often `slick` slider causes your function to be called as that could be causing performance issues also.

The above may not fix your TBT but is good practice anyway.

Comment: THX - you're great. I've startet to remove all lazyLoading for elements above the fold and the LCP was instantly better. In a next step I will realize your other hints :)

Comment: Glad I could help!